# How to update sum through Ajax in Ruby on Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery

I am building an Invoicing application where an **Invoice** can have various **Items**.

In the invoice view I have a row like this for every item:

```
<%= f.text_field :price %>
<%= f.text_field :quantity %>
```

A new item can be added to an invoice using Ajax, i.e. without resubmitting the page.

This works pretty well.

It would be nice, though, if the **total** of all the items would get updated through Ajax as well, without the user having to resubmit the page every time.

Can anybody tell me how this can be done?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: if you're updating the form elements ajaxically, in what way are you struggling to update a total value?

Answer (score 0):

You should considering using some kind of front end MVC or MVVM framework to handle this. Take a look at knockoutjs:

> Simplify dynamic JavaScript UIs by applying the Model-View-View Model (MVVM) pattern

http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections **<-- this tutorial shows almost exactly what you would be after.**

Basically, you would setup a viewModel that would represent your view which would have a collection of line entries, this would be "observable" which means in knockout language whenever it is changed (added to or deleted from) your binding to it would be updated. For example it could be a  with 's bound to each line item.

Then you can have a calculated observable which would update automatically

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your existing code. Do you submit / receive data in JSON format? Try to use some kind of client-side processing (plain javascript, jQuery or other framework).

Or you use more traditional Rails `:remote` form with js.erb templates? If so, you can update the invoice total in the create.js.erb . Something like (I assume the invoice total is wrapped with a tag with id="total", item belongs_to invoice, invoice has total field)

```
... # your current code
$("#total").update("<%= escape_javascript(@item.invoice.total)%>");
```

Same for delete and update actions.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your help. I am indeed trying to follow to "traditional" Rails way here, i.e. using a *create.js.erb* file. Unfortunately, I have no knowledge of jQuery at all, so I gratefully added your code to my *create.js.erb*. However, I couldn't get it to work yet. Still trying to find out why... I posted my code above...